# Error This feature is not implemented SQL ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I have read [this post](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Oracle/PL-SQL/howtopassaNULLvaluetoEXECUTEIMMEDIATE.htm) about USING clause in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statements:
Then I just wanted to test it  for non-null values:

```
declare mydate date;
begin
mydate := to_date('01.01.2001','dd.mm.yyyy');
execute immediate 'insert into test_testik(DATEZ)
                   values :x' using mydate;
end;
```

The result is following error 
03001. 00000 -  "unimplemented feature"
*Cause:    This feature is not implemented.

Any ideas why does this happen?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your insert statement is missing parenthesis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should surround `:x` with parentheses according to Oracle syntax.

Comment: Thank you, Egor!  But in what manner should I surround it? :)

Comment: The  thing I really adore about stackoverflow is that you get the answers immediately! =)

Comment: Quicker than looking in the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2122346

Comment: @DavidAldridge - Error message is very obscure, it doesn't point to wrong syntax.